# ModelSim Altera simulation error for a code that compiles correctly: Fatal error in process

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus, hardware

The code I am writing is really simple, only a few lines, and it is used for a simple led matrix display. It compiles correctly on Quartus II, but when I try to simulate it using ModelSim I get a fatal error at a certain line. My testbench is really simple as well and I have tried removing this line of code or simplifying it and the simulation is launched without problems (although the program does not do what it is supposed to).

I am new to VHDL and Quartus/ModelSim so I would appreciate a detailed explanation.
Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
--Entity definiton (top level entity).
entity entity is
    Port (  finalDisplay   : out     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);    
            sevenSegDisp   : out     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6  downto 0);    
            clkFast        : in      STD_LOGIC;                                 
            clkSlow        : in      STD_LOGIC);                                                                    
end entity;

architecture Behavioral of entity is
 --Interial signals
 signal frameCounter         : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8  downto 0) := (others => '0');  
 signal slowCounter          : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5  downto 0) := (others => '0');  
 type   display_t is array(4 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0);
 signal currentFrame         : display_t                      :=("0000000" ,                                                          
                                                                 "0000000" ,                                                                                         
                                                                 "0000000" ,         
                                                                 "0000000" ,          
                                                                 "0000000");                                                                                      
 signal row                   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0) := "11110";             
 signal col                   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0) := "0000001";         
 signal col_mask              : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0) := "0000000";        
 signal row_count             : UNSIGNED (2 downto 0)         := "001";            
 signal waveNumber            : UNSIGNED (3 downto 0)         := "0000";

begin           
    --Process Definition

displayCurrentFrame: process(clkFast)         
   begin
     if rising_edge(clkFast) then
       frameCounter <= frameCounter + 1;
            if frameCounter(4 downto 0) = "00000" then
                col <= col(5 downto 0) & col(6);
                if col = "1000000" then
                    row <= row(3 downto 0) & row(4);
                          if (to_integer(row_count) = 5) then
                                row_count <= "000";
                          end if;
                    row_count <= row_count + "1";
                    col_mask <= (currentFrame(to_integer(row_count))); --Fatal error at process displayCurrentFrame at fileName.vhd line thisLine.
                end if;
            end if;
            finalDisplay(4 downto 0) <= row;
            finalDisplay(11 downto 5) <= (col AND col_mask);
     end if;
   end process displayCurrentFrame;
end Behavioral;
```

I don't understand what is wrong with this particular line. Type casts/conversions seem correct to me.

Comment: Your example doesn't analyze. `entity entity is` should be `entity Space_Invaders is`. Semicolons and commas are separators in lists, extra semicolon at the end of port list. Missing closing `);` for port declaration. missing end statement for the architecture. Make frameCounter type unsigned, remove `use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;` which depends on package std_logic_arith  package numeric_std - don't mix and match. Please provide a [mcve] (and the actual simulator error message). the row_count increments wants to be in an else choice for the if statement assigning `row_count <= "000";`.

Comment: @user1155120 I had to remove some code to leave only what is relevant and it seems I created some errors that were not there. I had no else statement to begin with, I don't know if this caused the error..? I read up on what you said about the library and I removed it, could you explain why unsigned is better than std_logic_vector?

Comment: Your reported problem is cause by the index range of ` type   display_t is array(4 downto 0)` not matching the range of row_count. `if (to_integer(row_count) = 5) then` could be `if row_count = 4 then`. After all these corrections your code analyzes, elaborates, and with a supplied `clkfast`  simulates (while not making any apparent sense). Each declaration is unique even with the same name and subtype. The unsigned used for to_integer isn't the same unsigned declared in std_logic_arith used by std_logic_unsigned. Don't mix and match arithmetic packages between IEEE and Synopsys.

Comment: The cause of the bounds mismatch was both not having the increment in the else and going beyond 4 in the if statement. A signal assignment doesn't take effect in the current simulation cycle. Signal updates occur at the beginning of a simulation cycle before any process resumes. There's only one waveform update scheduled for any simulation time in the projected output waveform. A subsequent signal assignment will displace the pending assignment.

Comment: @user1155120 you're right, I fixed the problem. I have however a follow up question if you can answer or direct me to an answer. Using a testbench I would like to monitor the waveform not only of input/output signals but also of internal signals (e.g currentFrame)...I am guessing there is a way to do this.

Comment: Add the internal signals to the waves with right click, you can find them after launching the simulation in your left pannel "objects".

Comment: You have to add the internal signals from the objects, 'restart' and then 'run all' in the tool bar, in case someone is looking for that.